# Condensing repetitive .mouseover functions

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to condense the amount of repetitive jQuery for a mouseover function.

This may seem like a very basic task, but I am having a hell of a time trying to figure this out.

I am trying to make it so that when the mouse hovers over one of the the linked image the copy in one of the corresponding div ids imgdesc, imgdesc2, and imgdesc3 becomes visible.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#a").mouseover(function() { $("#imgdesc").css('visibility','visible'); });
$("#a").mouseout(function() { $("#imgdesc").css('visibility','hidden'); });
$("#b").mouseover(function() { $("#imgdesc2").css('visibility','visible'); });
$("#b").mouseout(function() { $("#imgdesc2").css('visibility','hidden'); });
$("#c").mouseover(function() { $("#imgdesc3").css('visibility','visible'); });
$("#c").mouseout(function() { $("#imgdesc3").css('visibility','hidden'); });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="r_column">
    <div id="bgimg1">
        <div class="imgcont">
            <a id="a" href="#">
                <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="imgdesc">
            <h1>Title</h1><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bgimg1">
        <div class="imgcont">
            <a id="b" href="#">
                <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="imgdesc2">
            <h1>Title</h1><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bgimg1">
        <div class="imgcont">
            <a id="c" href="#">
                <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="imgdesc3">
            <h1>Title</h1><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
            <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#bgimg1{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    height: 212px;
    display: inline-block;
}


.r_column{
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width:904px;
    float: right;
}

.imgcont{
    float: right;
    width: 461px;
    margin: 10px 12px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
}

div#imgdesc,div#imgdesc2,div#imgdesc3{
visibility:hidden;
text-align:right;
float:right;
width:395px;
margin: 10px 0px 10px 10px;
position: relative;
}
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `data-attribute` on the elements you want to hover and set as a value the selector for the element you want to reveal. e.g.

```
<div class="imgcont">
    <a id="a" href="#" data-target="#imgdesc">
        <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div id="imgdesc">
    <h1>Title</h1><br>
    <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
    <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
</div>
```

Then the JS is pretty simple.

```
$('[data-target]').hover(

function () {
   $( $(this).attr('data-target')).show()
},

function () {
    $($(this).attr('data-target')).hide()
});
```

But you could also do it with css only:

```
.imgcont:hover + div  { display:none;}
```

were you should probably change `div` to a more suitable selector.

Comment: So lets say we have
data-target="#a"
data-target="#b"
data-target="#c"

because each require a unique id to identify their target
<div id="a">
<div id="b">
<div id="c">

it increase the amount of css div#
#a,#b,#c{
display:none;
}

so is there a way to use only one data-target, one id, and one css div#?

Comment: If you have a pattern for your id's or classes e.g. `#hiding-a`, `#hiding-b` etc. you can target them all via `[id^='hiding-']` or `[id$='hiding-']` don't overdo it though. More on CSS Attribute selectors on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Will I break the internets if I "overdo it"? :D

But, really though. I'll be using this method maybe a dozen and a half times (possibly more).

Comment: No need to worry, it is just a selector, as long as they are readable and self expalaining, you're good. but using something like `[data-f$='-b']` will surely confuse you if you see it in a month.

Answer (score 4):

Modify your DOM so that there is a semantic relationship between buttons and their elements, and then you can use a single event handler. You can do this easily with `<a>` tags by placing the `id` of your target element into the `href` of the link:

```
    <div class="imgcont">
        <a id="a" href="#imgdesc">
            <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="imgdesc">
        <h1>Title</h1><br>
        <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
        <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
    </div>
```

You can simply your event handling by using `hover` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`:

```
$("a").hover(
  function () { $($(this).attr("href")).show(); }),
  function () { $($(this).attr("href")).hide(); })
);
```

In the handler, `$(this).attr("href")` returns `"#imgdesc"`, allowing you to immediately select the correct element based on which `<a>` is being hovered.

Comment: Not that I'm disagreeing that this is a good idea, but what if I plan on linking something through that href?

The over all plan with this page is to hover the curser over an image  for its description that pops up on the left hand side.

Comment: Then use a data attribute as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to meager's response could be to show the siblings of the parent div of the a element...

```
<div class="imgcont">
    <a id="a" href="#" class="hoverimage">
        <img src="pic/blackbox.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
</div>
<div class="hidden">
    <h1>Title</h1><br>
    <p class="subs">Name: Example</p><br>
    <p class="subs">Name: Example</p>
</div>

 //in your javascript
    $(".hoverimage").hover(
      function () { $(this).parent().siblings().show(); }),
      function () { $(this).parent().siblings().hide(); })
    );
```

You could apply a basic display:none to all .hidden elements.

Comment: DOM traversal is definitely slower than simply selecting the correct element, and less semantically valid.